# Remove Compiler info in external terminal vscode C++

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

I am using ubuntu 20. When I run a C++ code in VScode there shows a addition information probably of compiler. I want to remove/hide that information.

This is my launch.json:

```
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Id of student: 123
Enter Class of student: 10
Enter Full-name of student: Sudeep Poudel
Enter Section of student (A:1/B:2/C:3): 3
Enter Father's Full name of student: Abc Def
```

The info I want to hide:

```
12310�218453�[1] + Done     "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-91j6w8v0.v2m" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-0weto4fp.1kz"

Press any key to continue...
```

[image: The output]

[image: The error]

Comment: `launch.json` has nothing to do your compiler. It controls your debug process. `tasks.json` deals with your compile command. My guess is you're not intending to debug your program but just run it.

Comment: Are you manually running your program in a terminal visual studio code has used for debugging? Try using a fresh terminal window to run your program

Comment: Why can't you enter A or B or C? `gdb` is used to run/debug your program. gdb is not a compiler